# How to Show Links on Wordpress Blog View Page

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on Wordpress based website and trying to show links on Wordpress blog view page ( see page [here](http://frcawley.co.uk/rubbish-removal-tips/)), but the links are converted automatically to plain text. I have tried this code but without success:

```
<?php
function keep_my_links($text) {
  global $post;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace('\]\]\>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text, '<a>');
  }
  return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'keep_my_links');
?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: I see no plain text links. Where are they?

Comment: I have removed them because the Wordpress removes the formatting. Now have added a link to show you. When you open the post: "New Fines For Households Who Use Fly-Tippers" - at the beginning of the text there is a link with anchor: "rubbish removal services". But on the blog main page the link is missing.